# How to conceptually implement brute-force / tree traversal?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tree, brute-force

As a beginner programmer, I don't know how to conceptually think about brute-forcing. My mind can't really fathom how to write code that will try every possibility. My answer is **recursion**, but as you will see below, I have failed.

If you need the [full source](http://pastebin.com/jqgZuLuK)

I have a problem that I want to solve. Here is a code snippet (there are other functions, but no reason to include them here, they just do background work):

```
def initiate(seen):
        step_segment = []
        STATS = [250,0,0,0,13,0]

        if len(seen) >= 256:                    # when to escape the recursion
            return seen
        while (len(step_segment)) < 128:
            step_segment, STATS = take_step(step_segment, STATS)
            if STATS[5] == "B":                         # if there is a battle
                if STATS[0] in seen:             # if battle has been done before
                    status = seen.index(STATS[0])       # get battle status:
                    status += 1             # which is next to step_id (= G or B)
                    if seen[status] == "B":  # for seen battles, try Glitch ("G")
                        step_segment = do_glitch(step_segment, STATS)
                else:
                    step_segment, STATS = do_fight(step_segment, STATS) # fight
                seen = seen + [STATS[0],STATS[5]]

        time = get_frames(step_segment)
        print "\nTime:", time
        print seen
        return initiate(seen)
```

**The goal:** I want to produce a list of every possible decision through a segment, along with how long it takes.

**Description:**

1. I will take a step (There's only one direction: forward). Every time I take a step, my stats are updated. This takes a step and updates the stats: `step_segment, STATS = take_step(step_segment, STATS)`
2. A list of steps taken, along with the stats, are kept in
   `step_segment`. This is so I can 'undo' an arbitrary amount of
   steps, if I want. To undo a step call the function:
   `step_segment, STATS = undo_step(step_segment, STATS)`
3. I can see how long my current route has taken by doing: `time = frames(step_segment)`.
4. At some point, I will get into a Battle. I get into a battle when
   `STATS[5] == "B"`
5. When there is a battle I have to make a decision, I simply have two choices: **i.** Fight the
   battle (B), or, **ii.** Run away glitch (G).
6. If I want to Fight, I do: `step_segment = do_fight(step_segment, STATS)`. This also records that I chose to fight, along with the stats, in `step_segment`. (So I can undo it, if i want).
7. If I want to Run Away Glitch, I do: `step_segment = do_glitch(step_segment,STATS)`.

I want to see every possible combination of Glitch & Fight (the only two choices, when I reach a battle).

At the moment, my code is very bad and does not try all of the possibilities. I don't really know how to code for all possibilities.

So, that's why I'm here. How can I implement a way of trying all possibilities when facing a decision?

I understand the problem has exponential amount of possibilities, but thankfully the maximum number is pretty small (<1024).

I have read about tree traversal, but I have no idea how my problem can be put into that format. Eg, I don't know what a 'node' would be in my problem. I actually don't know what anything would be... That's why I'm asking.

Comment: Goodness this is a lot of stuff! You've got great ideas, and understandably sub-par implementation. There's lots of different ways to go about this, I'll see if I can write something up, but I'd do a lot of this with OOP that may not help you....

Comment: I think your code should try all the possibilities. Could you explain when exactly does it fail at that?

Comment: @adsmith it would be very helpful, even oop. I'm thinking of trying to re-write this problem with an OOP perspective, so it definitely would help, if you had the time!

Comment: @svick The current output is like this (each number is a battleID): 90:B, 136:B, 204:B [This is correct so far, it has seen 3 battles and fought them]. It eventually gets all the way through the segment and ends up doing 90:G, 136:G, 204:G ... 254:G.


But then it doesn't go back and try changing some of the G's for B's. For example, it SHOULD go back and change 90:G to 90:B, and have the rest G's. It doesn't do that.